# Read .CSV file and pass contents to ActiveMQ queue

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, csv, activemq-classic

I am trying to get a working example of:

- Having user view HTML page where they are presented with an upload button.

  - User uploads a .CSV which is then read and directed to and placed on a message queue (using ActiveMQ as a broker).

I was previously trying to use [Stomp.js](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) but have repeatedly run into issues with the connection dropping. (FYI I worked on this for hours but could not figure out how to read more than one frame before the connectgion dropped)

I then tried using ajax to trigger a python script but we are restricted to .WSGI at my company and wasn't sure if that was a lesser means to an end than javascript.

Does anyone have a good alternative for simply reading a .CSV file and placing the contents on an ActiveMQ queue? Preferably some sort of javascript / AJAX implementation?

Thanks for any help / direction you are willing to offer!

Comment: Do you have Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Both apache tomcat and Wildfly but we dont have alot of access to configure them.